# fsck: error 2 (No such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext2 for /dev/sda5

Tags: ubuntu, fsck

I'm new to Linux, I was trying to install Ubuntu using a 16gb usb.

I install Ubuntu and all was fine, then after to install Ubuntu in my pc, it appears a message that a new version of Ubuntu is required to install, I do it, and when the version was installed, it tell me that I need to restart my pc, I do it and then it appears this error.

```
fsck: error 2 (No such file or directory) while executing fsck.ext2 for /dev/sda5
```

It's an HP laptop.